# Where are the standard Javadoc tags documented?

Tags: tags, javadoc

Where can I find a complete, current list of the standard Javadoc tags, and instructions for each?

The latest I could find is the [JDK 8 list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javadoc.html#CHDJFCCC).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found it.  Here are the [standard Javadoc tags](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/javadoc/doc-comment-spec.html#standard-tags).

The API documentation has a link to the most current version of this list.
Find it under [module jdk.javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/jdk.javadoc/module-summary.html), section *See Also*.